# Displaying PDF from byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, byte

I am attempting to display a PDF file from data saved in my database.  It's in `byte[]` format.  The following code is successfully displaying the PDF file in a new IE tab, however, I am also getting an exception error in my try catch statement.

**My code sample:**

```
try {

     byte[] byteOutput = myObject.ContractBytes;
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=file.pdf");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     Response.BinaryWrite(byteOutput);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     RecordError(ex.Message, ex);
}
```

**My exception error:**

```
Thread was being aborted.
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)  
at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread() 
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
at GetForm.FromDatabase() in c:\\SRC\\GetPDF.aspx.cs:line 340
at GetForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\\SRC\\MyPage.aspx.cs:line 106
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Try calling `this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead of `Response.End()` - this will end the response and not throw the `ThreadAbortException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

> This method is provided only for compatibility with ASP—that is, for compatibility with
>   COM-based Web-programming technology that preceded ASP.NET. If you want to jump ahead to
>   the [EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and send a response to the client, it is usually preferable to call
>   [CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
>
> To mimic the behavior of the **End** method in ASP, this method tries to raise a
>   [ThreadAbortException] exception. If this attempt is successful, the calling thread will be
>   aborted, which is detrimental to your site's performance. In that case, no code after the call
>   to the End method is executed.
>
> If the End method is not able to raise a [ThreadAbortException], it instead flushes the response
>   bytes to the client. It does this synchronously, which can also be detrimental to your site's
>   performance.
>
> In either case (whether or not a [ThreadAbortException] exception is successfully raised), the
>   response pipeline jumps ahead to the [EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.
>
> The [CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does not raise
>   an exception, and code after the call to the [CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method might be executed. If
>   your intention is to avoid execution of subsequent code, and if the performance penalty of End
>   is acceptable, you can call End instead of [CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This code was written before I took over the position.  Thanks for your answer that you provided.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following statement is generating that error.

```
Response.End();
```

Why do you need it? Did you try the code without this call?